# How to sort Results in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am using Realm with Swift. I want to sort "pictures" saved in Realm by `PhotoCollectionViewController` in the reverse order of date. I don't know what should I do. I would be pleased if you could lend me your wisdom.

Models.swift

```
import RealmSwift

class Entry: Object {
    @objc dynamic var text = ""
    @objc dynamic var date = Date()
    let pictures = List<Picture>()
    }
class Picture: Object {
    @objc dynamic var fullImageName = ""
    @objc dynamic var thumbnailName = ""
    @objc dynamic var entry : Entry?
    }
```

PhotoCollectionViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class PhotoCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var pictures : Results<Picture>?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getPictures()
    }

    func getPictures() {
        if let realm = try? Realm() {
            pictures = realm.objects(Picture.self)
            //I want to sort pictures in the reverse order of date
            collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
…
}
```

Comment: `realm.objects(Picture.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)`?

Comment: I tried, but pictures becomes nil and the project will stop because of "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error.

Comment: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" doesn't tell me much. What is printed in the logs?

Comment: Error log is as follows. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot sort on key path 'date': property 'Picture.date' does not exist.'

Comment: I just realised that `Picture` does not have a `date`. `Entry` does. Did you mean to get and sort `Entry` objects instead?

Comment: Now I have multiple Picture objects in the Entry. And, in PhotoCollectionViewController, I want to get only Picture objects. 
How would I get all the sorted photos if I get a sorted Entry object?

Comment: Try `.flatMap { $0.pictures }`

Comment: The reason these answers that are all over the place is the question is unclear. The question asks about sorting a list in realm. However, the
*Picture Objects* being loaded are not in a list and also, they do not have a date property. So asking *I want to sort pictures in the reverse order of date* won't work. That being said, your *Entry Object* has a date and it has a List of *Picture Objects*. So the *Entry Objects* can be sorted by date which means the associated Picture List would be associated with that object's date. But again, the pics have no date property so they have no ordering.

Comment: I'm sorry that my question was unclear. I could understand how to get List<Entry> thanks to Sweeper's answer, but I don't know how to handle this List... I think it's the simple solution to create date property in Picture? Anyway, I'll try on my own.Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to sort it with the following code

```
realm.objects(Picture.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)
```

Comment: I tried, but pictures becomes nil and the project will stop. Error log is as follows. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot sort on key path 'date': property 'Picture.date' does not exist.' Now I have multiple Picture objects in the Entry. And, in PhotoCollectionViewController, I want to get only Picture objects.

Comment: It sound like you doesn't have any field in the Realm database for Picture which is named "date". You need to update byKeyPath with the row name which contains your date

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I solved it myself. I changed "pictures" as follows, 
I was able to do what I expected.

```
pictures = realm.objects(Picture.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "entry.date", ascending: false)
```

Thank you for the answers and advice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to sort the `Entry` objects and then `flatMap` to a bunch of `Picture`s:

```
var pictures = realm.objects(Entry.self)
                   .sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)
                   .flatMap { $0.pictures }
```